# Gas hob without burner cover

Tags: gas

Rather than having the gas spread out by the burner cover like this:

[image: hob]

I would like to have one central flame. Can I do this by removing both the burner cover and the burner itself leaving this:

[image: hob without cover]

Firstly, would this even burn as there isn't an air inlet like the burner has. Secondly is it safe?

The reason for doing this is because I have a small radius coffee maker:
[image]

Comment: Do not even try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The burner and gas orifice are configured to give a proper air-fuel mixture so the appliance can safely be used to burn the gas completely into carbon dioxide and water.

With the burner removed, you won't even have the equivalent of a good propane torch or lab Etna and with an improper air-fuel mixture, soot and carbon monoxide can be part of the resultant combustion output.

Your main problem is that you're trying to use a camp stove/hiking coffee maker on a kitchen range.

This device is sized for use with alcohol stoves, butane burners, their propane canister kin or propane camp stoves which all have a small burner diameter.

[image]

The best bet would be a sort of conical chimney that sits over the kitchen range burner on top of the grate and funnels the heat up to a smaller grate that your coffee maker sits on. If you look through the various online camping forums, you might find someone already makes these.

Comment: You're welcome! The online resources for alcohol and woodchip rocket stoves made from all sorts of materials is pretty phenomenal. Nothing like some hot soup on a hike just after you've encountered one of those rain showers. A hot cup of coffee would be the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is using a small coffee maker on a gas burner for which the supports are too far apart, there is a product for that:
[image]

Supposedly called a "stove hob reducer".

I've seen them being sold in the spare parts stores.

Comment: Also, I have actually tried to ignite the gas without the cover. You get a very tall flame, so be sure that nothing is directly above the burner. One problem however is that the thermocouple will no longer come in contact with the flame, so you will have to bypass it manually by holding down the valve (power setting)...  and a bunch of other issues.